# How does this for() work?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've come across the following for in some code:

```
for (i = M, j = N; i; )
```

`i,j,M,N` are all integers; what does the for do?

Comment: as long as i is <> 0 it will work.

Comment: it's equal to `i = M, j = N; while(i)`

Comment: `i` and `j` will be initialized once to the respective values (here `,` is just a separator and you can give as many statements separated by `,` in sections (init1,init2,init3; condition check; adjustment1,  adjustment2, adjustment3). Here `init` part gets executes only once. And for every condition check the adjustments and body part(if any) gets executed.
So in your case, as long as `i != 0`, the body and adjustments(no adjustments in your case) will gets executed.
**Note**: if nothing is given in condition part, by default it is considered as `true (!=0)`

Answer (score 5):

it's the same as

```
i = M;
j = N;

while (i != 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Made a pedantic edit since you don't know the type of `i` and `j`: the OP must have declared them elsewhere.

Comment: Further pendantanc point. It would be `while (i)` not `while (i != 0)`

Comment: I chose (i != 0) to make it more clear what happens but of course you are right. I wouldn't write (i != 0) aswell

Answer (score 1):

This for loop's exit condition is `i`, `i` is an `int`, it is implicitly convertible to `bool` which means that the loop will run until `i == 0` (because `0` evaluates to `false`, any other value evaluates to `true`). The loop itself doesn't modify `i` though so if the body of the loop doesn't either then you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The loop can be rewritten to

```
i = M;
j = N;
while(i) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

```
for (i = M, j = N; i; )
```

The above for loop, initializes i to M, j to N, and loops till i is non-zero (or false). In case, the value of i is not changed within the for loop, the loop will execute indefinitely.

**Long Answer:**

In a for loop, there are three parts (from [C++ standard guidelines](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.8.5.3.html))

```
for (clasue-1 ; expression-2; expression-3 )
```

where (emphasize on **bold** text)

> - The expression >expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>     evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> - The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression
>     after each execution of the loop body.
> - If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any variables identifiers
>     it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop,
>     including the other two expressions. **it is reached in the order of
>     execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression**.
> - **Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted.**

So in your case,

clause-1 is

> i = M, j = N

which is the declaration/initialization of i and j to be used within the for loop.

expression-2 is

> i

As expression-2 is supposed to be a boolean expression, the value of i governs the exit condition. Usually a value of 0 is considered false while all other values are true. So the loop will execute until the value of i is 0.

So your loop translates to

> i = M; j = N;
>
> while(i) { // statements.  }

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ you can use `int` as a Boolean variable. Actually, in C it does not even exist a bool.

The most common form of a for loop looks like this:

```
for(init; condition; increment)
```

It has three statements, so the second statement is simply something that can be evaluated to true or false, which an integer can.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = M, j = N; i; ) {
    // body
}
```

is the same as:

```
i = M;
j = N;
while (i != 0) {
    // body
}
```

If `M != 0` and `i` doesn't change inside the `for` loop body you have an infinite loop.